# Given a Facebook app's page/id, how do I find how many "likes" that app has?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

farmville/frontierville/etc

How do I figure out how many "likes" these apps have?
The graph API does not work with apps.

Answer (score 2):

The graph api below will show all the information related to the app

https://graph.facebook.com/159616034235/

result:

[image]

Comment: yeah it does showing an error message, are you sure the app (dominodraw) exists or the fan page is published

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID
```

Try this example call in [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/farmville
```

which will return a JSON reponse with id, name, picture, link and then likes as 5th value.

Comment: I get this: {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: myfarmx",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}  http://graph.facebook.com/dominodraw/

Comment: If you use Farmville's username "farmville" or Farmville's id 208633805894647 it works. Frontierville has changed name to The Pioneer Trail, so call /thepioneertrail instead. But it's possible the visibility of this information can be blocked by the app admin at their discretion. Do you have dominodraw's app id - ? The response seems to indicate 'dominodraw' is not the registered name for the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of likes from Graph API by querying by Application `id` or Application `namespace`.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID_OR_NAMESPACE
```

You can also limit results to be only constructed from `id` of an application and `likes` by using `fields` argument in URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID_OR_NAMESPACE?fields=likes
```

Beware that not every application have a `namespace` defined and because name of application is not unique, it's better to use `id` of application to retrieve details from Graph API

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. The graph API does <strike>not</strike> work with apps.

http://www.facebook.com/dominodraw/

takes me to 'page not found'. So, `dominodraw` is not a valid facebook username.

Try `graph.facebook.com/<your_app_id>` and it will get likes for your app.

*p.s. Just in case you are confused.*

`farmville` is not only the name of app, but also they have registered `farmville` as facebook username.

So, they can do `https://graph.facebook.com/farmville` along with `graph.facebook/208633805894647`

If you havent set username for your app, you can only call graph api by `app_id`.